# scan list of lists in python finding specific characters on elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I've got a problem with find a way for visit a particular list of list in python.

this is the situation:

I've got a list of list like this with some 1 and some 0:

```
matrix = 
    [
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ]
```

so I enter in the list of list in a specific coordinate like this

```
y = 3
x = 3
```

and from this position I need to mark (example with a 2) all the coordinates near of the start position where 1 is in the box.
Stop when I've marked all the positions close of the starting point with 2.

This is the expected result:

```
expected_matrix = 
    [
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,2,2,2,2,0,1],
     [0,2,2,2,2,0,1],
     [0,2,2,2,2,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    ]
```

Edit:
I can't scan all the lists, because I'm not interested to mark every 1 but only the closest (alongside of a 0 inside the starting point coordinates (rows ad cols)) of the starting point

Thanks.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want. Maybe add an expected result or output to the program you need, so we can better understand?

Comment: How are you "traverse" ing?

Comment: @BobbyLinux - Please let us know if one of posts help you or you have other follow-up questions?

Comment: no, these aren't helpful!

Answer (score 0):

since your description is not clear, so I just make some assumptions here:

1. the given x, y is the staring coordinate to travel
2. the travel direction is right, then down
3. along the `path` it will mark all `1` to become `2`.
   Based on these assumptions, the problem can be solve this way:

```
matrix =[
         [0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,0], #     ???
         [0,1,1,1,1,1], # <- 3, 3?
         [0,0,0,0,1,1],
        ]

R = len(matrix)    # 5
C = len(matrix[0]) # 6


start_r, start_c = 3, 3

for i in range(start_r, R):
    for j in range(start_c, C):
        #print(i, j, matrix[i][j])   #can comment out
        matrix[i][j] = 2    # mark it to 2

print(matrix)
```

Comment: if you look the edit of the post this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally I've found a solution.

```
#upside
for yy in range(y,-1,-1):
   if matrix[yy][x] == 0:
      break
      for xx in range(x,-1,-1):
          if matrix[yy][xx] == 0:
             break
          matrix[yy][xx] = 2
      for xx in range(x+1, len(matrix[y])):
          if matrix[yy][xx] == 0:
             break
          matrix[yy][xx] = 2
#downside
for yy in range(y, len(matrix)):
   if matrix[yy][x] == 0:
      break
      for xx in range(x,-1,-1):
          if matrix[yy][xx] == 0:
             break
          matrix[yy][xx] = 2  
      for xx in range(x+1, len(matrix[y])):
          if matrix[yy][xx] == 0:
             break
          matrix[yy][xx] = 2
```

maybe could be a recursive solution but this could help me anyway!